PineScript V5 - Basic Script Repaint problem
I have a pretty basic code that long above SMA200, and short below SMA200, with take profit and stop loss function. It runs fine, but when I want to set an alarm, TV said it uses repaint data, could you please point out where the problem is?
//@version=5

strategy(shorttitle='AVG200', title='AVG200', overlay=true, currency = currency.USDT, initial_capital = 100, default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value = 100,commission_value = 0.035, calc_on_order_fills=false)

takeprofit      = input.float   (500, minval=0.1, maxval=500, step=0.1)/100
stoploss        = input.float   (50,  minval=0.1, maxval=50,  step=0.1)/100
TP              = strategy.position_size == 0 ? na : strategy.position_size > 0 ? strategy.opentrades.entry_price(0)*(1+takeprofit) : strategy.opentrades.entry_price(0)*(1-takeprofit)
SL              = strategy.position_size == 0 ? na : strategy.position_size < 0 ? strategy.opentrades.entry_price(0)*(1+stoploss) : strategy.opentrades.entry_price(0)*(1-stoploss)

basis = ta.sma(close, 200)
plot(basis, linewidth=1, color=color.new(color.white,0))

long_entry1     = close > basis
short_entry1    = close < basis

close_long1     = close < basis
close_short1    = close > basis

close_longTP    = close > TP
close_longSL    = close < SL
close_shortTP   = close < TP
close_shortSL   = close > SL

if barstate.isconfirmed
    if long_entry1
        strategy.entry("L", strategy.long, comment="Long")
    if short_entry1
        strategy.entry("S", strategy.short, comment="Short")
        
    if close_long1
        strategy.close("L", "Close Long") 
    if close_short1
        strategy.close("S", "Close Short")
        
    if close_longTP
        strategy.close("L", "Long Take Profit") 
    if close_shortTP
        strategy.close("S", "Short Take Profit")
            
    if close_longSL
        strategy.close("L", "Long Stop Loss") 
    if close_shortSL
        strategy.close("S", "Short Stop Loss")

Try Different set of if function, but it still have the repaint problem.
